# HTML FORM - Change Parts Of Readonly String Field Using onchange()

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onchange

I want to assign the values - value and value 2 into the DATAID and DEPNUM when clicking the drop-down and using onchange() function in the following HTML FORM
The places that are being assigned are parts of a readonly field which contains string. 
My goal is to create a readonly string which will contain the values that I've chosen from the dropdown fields, all combined in 1 string and separated by underscore.

[image: assign value2 into DATAID in the string and assign value in the DEPNUM]

I've been trying to use onChange method "myFunction()"

```
<input name="_1_1_2_1" tabindex="-1" class="valueEditable" id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()" type="text" size="32" value="...">
```

which will look like :

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

eventually I run it on the paragraph :

```
<p id="demo" value="DATAID_DOCTYPE_DEPNUM_NTA">DATAID_DOCTYPE_DEPNUM_NTA</p>
```

The problem is that the value at

is not changing instant as i change value2 or value.

Comment: Please could you share your HTML and JavaScript so we can see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind two event-listener for both two input fields and updated the readonly textfield value by below approach.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#field1').keyup(function() {
    updatedReadonlyFieldVal($(this), 0);
  });
  
  $('#field2').keyup(function() {
    updatedReadonlyFieldVal($(this), 2);
  });
  
  function updatedReadonlyFieldVal(elem, index) {
    let val = elem.val();
    let destVal = $('#destination').val();
    let splittedDestVal = destVal.split('_');
    splittedDestVal[index] = val;
    $('#destination').val(splittedDestVal.join('_'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1">
<input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">

<input value="DATAID_DOCTYPE_DATANUM" readonly id="destination">
```

**Please don't hesitate to let me know if you have any query.**